# Multiple web.config files per environment

Tags: asp.net, web-config, octopus-deploy, web.config-transform

I have several several web.config files:

- Web.config
- Web.Debug.config
- Web.Dev.config
- Web.IntTest.config
- Web.ProdTest.config
- Web.Prod.config

Where Web.config is the main config file and the rest are transformation files.

I am using Octopus Deploy for deployment and it automatically uses the correct transformation when I deploy to each environment. However, if I were to build the soultion locally, it would use transform Web.config using Web.Debug.config, meaning the main will be changed, so if I would now check in the solution my Web.config would be transformed using Web.Debug.config transformations, which would be incorrect.

I can only imagine that this is a common issue and there has to be a standard way of solving this, however I haven't been able to find anything myself.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Not sure if that is a solution for you - I just don't user Web.Debug.config (i.e. dev config is source against all transformations are running).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that aswell, and maybe that is the standard way of doing it? I didn't set up this specific structure so I don't know why it is set up this way.

Comment: This seems to be the correct way of doing this, so if you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

A few options for you

1. Don't use Web.Debug.config like mentioned in the comments
2. Have Web.Release.config have all the transformations needed to correct the web.config

I like the second approach because it prevents someone from changing the base web.config (with or without help from transforms) and it getting to production. We effectively treat Web.config like the debug config file.